# My JLabel goes out of my JFrame by moving it

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, keylistener

By the first sorry for the worst English ever.

I've made a code for moving a `JLabel`, It works fine.  But when I hold my arrow keys, my label goes out of my `JFrame`.

Here's my code:

This is my view:

```
package view;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import controller.Keys;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class View extends JFrame{

public JLabel plaatje = new JLabel();
public static View instance;

public static View getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new View();
    }
    return instance;
}

public View() {
    setSize(700,700);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setFocusable(true);
    this.addKeyListener(new Keys());
    setLayout(null);
    plaatje.setIcon(new ImageIcon(View.class.getResource("/images/linksloop.png")));
    add(plaatje);
    plaatje.setBounds(0, 500, 70, 70);

}

}
```

And here's my controller:

```
package controller;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import view.View;

public class Keys implements KeyListener{

public boolean isLeftPressed;
public boolean isRightPressed;
public boolean isSpacePressed;


@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            switch(e.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                setLeftPressed(true);
                left();
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                setRightPressed(true);
                right();
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                setSpacePressed(true);
                space();
            break;
            }   
        }  

         });        

        t.start();
}

public void left(){

    if (isLeftPressed == true) {

        View.getInstance().plaatje.setIcon(new ImageIcon(View.class.getResource("/images/linksloop.png")));


        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            View.getInstance().plaatje.setLocation(View.getInstance().plaatje.getX() - 10, View.getInstance().plaatje.getY());

            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            View.getInstance().plaatje.repaint();
        }           
    }
}

public void space(){

    if (isSpacePressed == true) {

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){

            View.getInstance().plaatje.setLocation(View.getInstance().plaatje.getX(), View.getInstance().plaatje.getY() - 10);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            View.getInstance().plaatje.repaint();

        }
            for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){

            View.getInstance().plaatje.setLocation(View.getInstance().plaatje.getX(),   View.getInstance().plaatje.getY() + 10);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            View.getInstance().plaatje.repaint();


        }
    }
}

public void right(){

    if (isRightPressed == true) {

        View.getInstance().plaatje.setIcon(new   ImageIcon(View.class.getResource("/images/rechtsloop.png")));


        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            View.getInstance().plaatje.setLocation(View.getInstance().plaatje.getX() + 10,   View.getInstance().plaatje.getY());

            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            View.getInstance().plaatje.repaint();
        }           
    }

}


@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public boolean isLeftPressed() {
    return isLeftPressed;
}

public void setLeftPressed(boolean isLeftPressed) {
    this.isLeftPressed = isLeftPressed;
}

public boolean isRightPressed() {
    return isRightPressed;
}

public void setRightPressed(boolean isRightPressed) {
    this.isRightPressed = isRightPressed;
}

public boolean isSpacePressed() {
    return isSpacePressed;
}

public void setSpacePressed(boolean isSpacePressed) {
    this.isSpacePressed = isSpacePressed;
}


}
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: So what else you expect to happen ?

Comment: I want that when i move my JLabel, it stays inside of my frame.. and not go outside.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: This is all i've got.

Comment: *"This is all i've got."*  If you are replying to @joeyrohan, note that an MCVE is never two separate pieces of code.  It must be a single copy/paste, compile run/see.  It can contain more than one class, but they all must be in the same package (hopefully that is obvious) & it can contain only one **`public`** class..

Comment: BTW - if this is the only content of the frame I'd dump the current approach and position the label in the parent element using an `EmptyBorder`.  To move the image, change the parameters of the border.  If OTOH there is more than one element on screen, I'd also dump the current approach and do it all using custom painting.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking against the dimensions of the JFrame (once it's been packed so that Java knows the bounds of the object).

1. get the position of the left hand side of the JFrame.
2. check that getX() - 10 is not less than this value.
3. if getX() - 10 is less than this value, do not move.

Repeat for the other movement commands. I'd post up example code, but I'm in a hurry. Will edit if necessary later on.

Comment: Can you post an example if you have time? what i'm doing wont work.

Comment: I've had a look at your code, and there are various reasons why it won't work. You're not packing the `JFrame`, nor are you making it visible. You have no main class to test with. Your images aren't being referenced correctly. Even solving all of this, your `JFrame` isn't displaying properly. I recommend walking yourself through a tutorial on the subject :) - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html